# How to fill a 2D array with user inputted values?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a program in java to fill a 2D array with user inputted values. The program works perfectly when both the rows and columns are specifed to the same value (square matrix). But, when the values are different, it doesn't print and throws an index out of bounds exception and I can't seem to figure out why. I have attached my code below.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x; //columns
    int y; //rows

    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows of the matrix:");
    y = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns of the matrix:");
    x = console.nextInt();

    int[][] matrix = new int[y][x];
    fillMatrix(y, x, matrix);
}
```

```java
public static void fillMatrix(int row, int col, int[][] matrix) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int quantity = (row * col); //number of numbers in matrix
    System.out.println("Please enter " + quantity +
            " integers separated by spaces:");
    for (int cinput = 0; cinput < row; cinput++) { //column
        for (int rinput = 0; rinput < col; rinput++) { //row
            //Read the line of integers to fill positions in the array.
            matrix[cinput][rinput] = console.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            //Outputs the array in a xy grid.
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your output code, change the order of `i` and `j`.  So change `matrix[i][j]` to `matrix[j][i]`.  And you probably should swap the order of the `for` loops as well so the row is on the outside and the column is on the inside.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thank you! this fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make a copy of all the numbers that you need to put into the matrix.
Hold a counter that will be increased only when you put a value into the matrix.
Continue Increasing the counter until you have no more values to put. When you are done simply get out of the loop.

Something like this

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
int x; //columns
int y; //rows 
System.out.println("Enter the number of rows of the matrix:");
y = myScanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the number of columns of the matrix:");
x = myScanner.nextInt();

int [][] matrix = new int [x][y]; 


myScanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the numbers seperated by space:");
String input = myScanner.nextLine();

String tmp            [] = input.split(" "); //holds the numbers that are inputted (String)
int    numbers        [] = new int[tmp.length];//array that holds the parsed numbers

for(int i = 0 ; i <numbers.length; i++)
  numbers[i] = (int)(tmp[i].charAt(0) - '0');  //parsing the numbers

// Logic that matters
int counter = 0; 

for(int k = 0; k < matrix.length && counter < numbers.length; k++)
{
 for(int j = 0 ; counter < numbers.length &&  j < matrix[k].length; j++)
 {
     matrix[k][j] = numbers[counter];
     System.out.print(matrix[k][j]+" ");
     counter = counter + 1; 
 }
 System.out.println("");
}
```

Input-

```
Enter the number of rows of the matrix:
3
Enter the number of columns of the matrix:
1
Enter the numbers seperated by space:
1 2 3
```

Output -

1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

In your output code, change the order of `i` and `j`.

So change:

```
matrix[i][j]
```

To:

```
matrix[j][i]
```

And you probably should swap the order of the for loops as well so the row is on the outside and the column is on the inside.

All together, that'd look like:

```
System.out.println();
for(int j = 0; j < row; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(matrix[j][i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```